# How to calculate Absolute error under square root sign?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I was calculating standard deviation of a data set. Could someone help me find the square root of 15.13 with an absolute error of 0.005? Is there a rule for calculating absolute errors under square root sign?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: Sorry It was a Chemistry lab calculation. I was calculating the standard deviation for the volume of water delivered by a pipette using mass and density of water ( at given temperature). Thank you for the reminder! I'll change it then.

Comment: I don't understand how the error of a square root would result from the experiment you described.

Comment: I recommend this publication, which also *correctly* covers the common circumstance of correlated noises: J. Tellinghuisen, "Statistical Error Propagation", J. Phys. Chem. A 105, 3917-3921 (2001).

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different approach to @Zhe's answer is to use the 'propagation of errors' formula. Your formula is $y=\sqrt{x}$  with $x=15.13$ and an error $\sigma_x=0.005$ then the formula becomes $\displaystyle \sigma_y=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\sigma_x = \frac{\sigma_x}{2\sqrt{x}}= 6.4\cdot 10^{-4}$.

[if you have a formula in more than one variable , say $x$ and $z$ then $y=f(x,z)$ and the equation is more complicated but still quite easy if done in steps and is $\displaystyle \sigma_y^2=\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} \right)^2_z\sigma^2_x+ \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dz} \right)^2_x\sigma^2_z$. Notice that the square of the final error is calculated in this case.]

Comment: This is much better for combining two uncorrelated errors than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to look at Taylor expansions when computing functions on small errors:

$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + O(x^{2})$$

This means that

$$\sqrt{15.13 \pm 0.005} = \sqrt{15.13}\sqrt{1 \pm \frac{0.005}{15.13}} = \sqrt{15.13}\left(1 \pm \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{0.005}{15.13}+O(0.005^{2})\right)$$